# Where to find 'The Art and Science of C' source code?

Tags: c, bgi

I am stuck in the a programming book 'The Art and Science of C', this book uses custom libraries, like graphics.h. I've tried many ways to find the libraries, I also connected to the Addison-Wesley FTP site mentioned in the appendix of the book, but it doesn't work. Anyone know where to get this libraries?

Comment: which compiler you are using ?

Comment: Mail them. Probably the website is down!

Comment: @Viswanathan This isn't true. graphics.h is not standard at all. See the Eric Pi's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That book was published in 1995.  While the basic C concepts should still be valid, any OS-specific or compiler-specific stuff will likely be quite out of date.  (Similarly, the book's FTP site is likely long gone.)  According to [this link](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/17709), it looks like graphics.h was part of an old Borland DOS compiler:

> graphics.h is a very old library for
>   doing graphics in DOS with Borland C++
>   3.x. It's not supported under Windows, and the compiler isn't supported
>   either.

You might try to find an old copy of Borland somewhere (and perhaps a VM in which to run it), or perhaps, find a newer C book.